# calculate average if all the columns have value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have below dataset

```
                Monday    Tuesday   Wednesday 
          ===================================

      Mike      42        NaN       12

      Jenna     NaN       NaN       15

      Jon       21        4         1
```

How to calculate the average  if all the values are present. In the above case only Jon should have average value other two none as they are missing value.
I tried different methods like `isnull()`, `notnull()` but nothing seems
work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case pass `skipna = False` when call `mean`

```
df.mean(skipna=False,axis=1)
Out[9]: 
Mike          NaN
Jenna         NaN
Jon      8.666667
dtype: float64
```